# Code to create ASP.Net membership database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-membership

Before I write this myself, is there a c# method out there floating around that will create the tables, sprocs, and views that get installed by aspnetregsql?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know there is no API to do this directly - the `aspnet_regsql.exe` tool just references script files on disk anyhow.

For a head start on how to implement this yourself:

You can manually execute `aspnet_regsql.exe` via `Process.Start`.

Or you can run the program from the command line, with command line options to dump out the script.  Then edit those scripts to be DB agnostic (or don't - up to you), store those scripts as embedded resources in your application, extract them at runtime, and use a `SqlConnection` and `ExecuteNonQuery` to run those scripts against a database.

Here are the command line options for `aspnet_regsql.exe`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862(v=vs.80).aspx

Here's some code I have used to implement the second option:

```
ExecuteSqlScriptResource("MyDb", "MyAssemblyName.Scripts.aspnet_regsql_add.sql");

// ...

static void ExecuteSqlScriptResource(string connectionName, string resourcePath)
{
    using (Stream scriptStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
        .GetManifestResourceStream(resourcePath)
        )
    {
        if (scriptStream == null)
        {
            WriteLine(string.Format("Failed to open resource {0}", resourcePath));
            return;
        }

        using (
            var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(
                ConfigurationManager
                    .ConnectionStrings[connectionName].ConnectionString
                )
            )
        {
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(scriptStream))
            {
                var svrConnection = new ServerConnection(sqlConnection);
                var server = new Server(svrConnection);
                server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: -sqlexportlonly <filename>   BAM!  ty sir

Comment: @andrew: Indeed :) It isn't DB agnostic, if that is a concern for you.  I edited that file manually.  If you want some slapped together code to execute that script I can give it to you later today.  About 10-15 lines.

Comment: @andrew: Glad this helped.  If the answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted (the check mark at the top-left of the answer).